# "Finder will be rewarded" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase

I want to translate the phrase

> Finder will be rewarded.

to German. Somehow there is no dictionary on the net which contained the phrase. I am looking for a metaphorical equivalent.

Comment: It's better to pick the most important words (finder, reward) and you'll find the answer by using Google and/or dictionaries: [Pons](http://en.pons.com/translate?q=reward+finder&l=deen&in=&lf=en), [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=finder+reward)

Comment: Would "a finder's reward" be possible in English?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could just remark *[Finderlohn](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finderlohn)!*

If you know, what you want to pay, you could combine it with the sum you want to pay.

Examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Such a sweet lil' donkey ^^. The "zu vergeben" from the last poster sounds unusual.

Comment: @Grantwalzer Thats kind of a eye-catcher. It is unusual, so you look for it. They have lost nothing, the look for a new flat. Normally you would offer a `Provision` - but that sounds too business-like.

Comment: @knut, what you probably mean is `commission`, oh I see what you are doing, you refer to the german word `Provision`

Answer (score 7):

In German you use a noun for this: [Finderlohn](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Finderlohn).

Answer (score 4):

Im ganzen Satz:

> Dem Finder winkt eine Belohnung.

Answer (score 1):

Some languages have words where other languages need whole sentences for.

In Germany we say "Finderlohn" which means "Reward for the finder".